# DataGridTextColumn ValidationRules doesn't trigger Validation.HasErrorProperty

Tags: wpf, mvvm, attached-properties, validationrules

I have a `DataGrid` with `DataGridTextColumn` on which I have a ValidationRule

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="xxx" IsReadOnly="False">
   <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
     <Binding Path="xxx" >
       <Binding.ValidationRules>
         <v:xxxValidator />
       </Binding.ValidationRules>
     </Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
```

I then have `b:BindValidationResult.HasError="{Binding HasError}"` on my `DataGrid`.

In `BindValidationResult` I use `Validation.HasErrorProperty` to listen on validationError changed.

My validation rule return `return new ValidationResult(false, "");`

My feeling is that I don't listen on the right property for a `DataGridTextColumn` because if I do the same thing with a `TextBox` it works like a charm.

Also, the `DataGridCell` get some red border when there is a error so I know that there is something happening.

I even tried this so see if the `Validation.HasError` would change but it doesn't trigger.

```
<Style.Triggers>
 <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
    <Setter
        Property="ToolTip" 
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Any help will be really appreciated on how to fix this or how to attack the problem.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `Binding.VaidationRules`, however I've always seen that Style Trigger for `Validation.HasError` used with the `IDataErrorInfo` interface on the bound data source itself. Perhaps it's not meant to be used with `Binding.ValidationRules`? `IDataErrorInfo` is the standard way of implementing validation in WPF.

Comment: Any reason why it is the standard way?

Comment: Are you trying to add error message on tooltip?

Comment: Nah, I am trying to show a label with an error message. The label visibility would have been binded to `HasError` property. But `HasError` property never changes when using a `DataGridTextColumn`. It does change when using a TextBox alone.

Comment: can you post more code replicating your issue.

Comment: I know I'm being vague but it is hard to post more code while not crossing the line.

Comment: Is there a way to access `DataGridCell`throught `DataGridTextColumm` in xaml as in adding my `BindValidationResult.HasError="{Binding HasError}"`on it instead of my `DataGrid`

Comment: @Ecnerwal WPF's binding system uses the `IDataErrorInfo` interface when validating bindings, so most WPF developers implement their validation using that interface. I don't think I've ever seen any WPF code where someone used `Binding.ValidationRules` instead.

Comment: This link from MSDN has a example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.haserror(v=vs.100).aspx